# foreman start fails with error "Please install daemon_controller first:"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, upstart, foreman

I want to monitor my app with upstart. I'm exporting using

```
rvmsudo foreman export upstart /etc/init -a <my_app_name> -u ubuntu -l /var/<my_app_name>/log
```

It finishes successfully, but when i do

```
sudo start <my_app_name>
```

I get the following output and nothing happens

```
<my_app_name> start/running
```

my procfile

```
web: rvmsudo passenger start -p80 -e production
worker: rvmsudo bundle exec rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=production
```

Its really frustrating because i can run the web and worker commands on different terminals individually. So I tried to just do a `foreman start` and this fails with the following error

```
 *** ERROR ***
Please install daemon_controller first:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/wrappers/gem install daemon_controller
```

The frustrating bit is that daemon controller is installed and i can see it when i do `gem list`

Maybe my whole approach to this is wrong can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's the line in passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/master/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/command.rb#L86-L87) that returns that error, so it looks as though it really can't find `daemon_controller` as it's rescuing a `LoadError`. Try updating your `web` process to run via `bundle exec` also:

```
web: rvmsudo bundle exec passenger start -p80 -e production
```